# My M-code is working in Power BI but not in DataFlow

Tags: powerquery, google-cloud-dataflow, power-platform

I have this M code and it's working in Power BI.
If I run it as a DataFlow I'm asked for cretidentials:

```
let
    InvoiceLine = 
        Json.Document(Web.Contents(
            "https://url.com", 
            [Headers=
                [
                    #"Authorization"="Basic *********", 
                    #"Content-type"="application/json"
                ]
            ]
        )
    ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(InvoiceLine)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Why is that?